# Wso2 enterprise integrator message context reading local entries on multitenancy

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

When we write a custom handler that extends AbstractHandler, and we try to read local entries from the message context, in case the api call is on a certain tenant, will the message context read the tenant local entries or the admin carbon super local entries?

```
public class CustomAPIAuthenticationHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) {
      // code here to read local entries from message contexnt
    }
}
```